# How can I get NSDecimal to round to the nearest integer value?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdecimal

I am using NSDecimal because I have to store extremely large values for my application. I would like to be able to use the NSDecimalDivide function to divide two NSDecimals and round the result to the nearest integer.

```
    NSDecimal testOne = [[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"1064"] decimalValue];
    NSDecimal cost = [[NSDecimalNumber    decimalNumberWithString:@"10"]decimalValue];
    NSDecimal value;
    NSDecimalDivide(&value, &testOne, &cost, NSRoundDown);
    NSString *string = NSDecimalString(&value, _usLocale);
    NSLog(@"Here is the cost%@",string);
```

This out puts 106.4 I would like it to output 106. Does anyone know how to round a NSDecimal number to the integer value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible way to do that is using a `NSDecimalNumberHandler` with `scale` set to `0`.

```
NSDecimalNumber *number1 = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"1064"];
NSDecimalNumber *number2 = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"10"];

NSDecimalNumberHandler *behavior = [[NSDecimalNumberHandler alloc] initWithRoundingMode:NSRoundDown
                                                                                  scale:0
                                                                       raiseOnExactness:NO
                                                                        raiseOnOverflow:NO
                                                                       raiseOnUnderflow:NO
                                                                    raiseOnDivideByZero:YES];

NSDecimalNumber *result = [number1 decimalNumberByDividingBy:number2 withBehavior:behavior];

NSLog(@"Here is the cost %@", result);
```

Note that I am not using the primitive `NSDecimal` at all and you I would advise you the same.

However, if you want to work with `NSDecimal` directly, you can use the handy `NSDecimalRound` function.

Answer (score 4):

Wrap the NSDecimal up as an NSDecimalNumber and use `decimalNumberByRoundingAccordingToBehavior:`. This lets you specify the exact rounding [behavior](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSDecimalNumberBehaviors_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/NSDecimalNumberBehaviors) you desire.